# use NLTK to identify direct speech

Tags: python, nltk

I want to label each sentence in a text as either direct speech or not direct speech. For example if the text was

```
1) Billy said, "Hello Jim".
2) Jim has happy.
```

sentence `1` would be labeled as direct speech and sentence `2` would be labeled as not direct speech.

Can this be done using python `NLTK`?